# What properties $f$ must have so that $\overline{f(z)} =f(\,\overline {z} \,)$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

What properties function $f$ must have so that $\overline{f(z)}  =f(\,\overline {z} \,)$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$

My working : I can prove it for f being a polynomial in $z$ with real coefficient using conjugates distributing properties.
I know how to prove  $\overline{\tan z}=\tan \overline z.$

I am searching for a necessary and sufficient condition on $ f$ for which it is true.

Please help me with sufficient but may not be necessary conditions also.

Comment: Analytic functions whose expansion about $0$ has only real coefficients is one sufficient requirement. But ultimately, I don't think there is a simple equivalent requirement other than $\overline{f(z)} = f(\bar z)$.

Comment: any constant $f\equiv z$ with $z$ non-real will not satisfy this and there are proabably tons of ways to modify this to get other examples. I do not see any simple necessary conditions either.

Comment: Also, the ones Artur said, but composed with the complex conjugate map (on the left or on the right: it's the same).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that $f$ is an entire function, then we have$$(\forall z\in\Bbb C):\overline{f(z)}=f\left(\overline z\right)\tag1$$if and only if $f(\Bbb R)\subset\Bbb R$. In fact, if we $(1)$, then, if $x\in\Bbb R$, $\overline{f(x)}=f\left(\overline x\right)=f(x)$, and so $f(x)\in\Bbb R$. And, if $f(\Bbb R)\subset\Bbb R$, then the function $g\colon\Bbb C\longrightarrow\Bbb C$ defined by $g(z)=\overline{f\left(\overline z\right)}$ is also analytic. But $g(x)=f(x)$ when $x\in\Bbb R$ and therefore, by the identity theorem, $f=g$. But this means that we have $(1)$.

Comment: i.e. if any real function $f$ extend to complex domain then this is true ?

Comment: If $f\colon\Bbb R\longrightarrow\Bbb R$ can be extended to a differentiable function from $\Bbb C$ into $\Bbb C$, then, yes, it is true.

Comment: (+1) and congratulations on reaching 300k! $(\ddot\smile)$

Comment: @VIVID Thank you.